# Is selenium a specific language oriented (like Java)?

Tags: selenium, qa-developer

I am a new learner of Selenium, after searching for tutorial and references, I found most of them based on Java Language, specially the webdriver part.
I am good at JavaScript, is that any good for this track ?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your first question:
In short, **no**. Selenium isn't binded to one language.

> I am good at JavaScript, is that any good for this track ?

**Yes**. You can use JavaScript with Selenium WebDriver.

Long answer:
There are many ways to do this.

For example: *WebDriverJS*

```
An Introduction to WebDriver Using the JavaScript Bindings
https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/an-introduction-to-webdriver-using-the-javascript-bindings--cms-21855
```

You should also check out: *WebDriverIO* and *Nightwatch*.

If you would like to get help with it I'll recommend you to try ["*The Selenium Guidebook JavaScript edition*"](https://seleniumguidebook.com/)
Great book, cheat sheets and video tutorials.

Please check out the [SeleniumHQ](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp) website for basic information about how WebDriver works :)

Comment: thanks
The book is nice but looks like it is not free :) I can not afford that one, is there any cheatsheet or tutorial for a boost up ? I am a quick learner

Comment: If you are quick learner then try learning Java or Python :) Seriously. There are a looot of materials there. But they are mostly for Java and Python.

If you really liek to stick with JS then here's good way to start:
http://nightwatchjs.org/

You got there demo test on the bottom of the page.

Here is a nice guide:
http://nightwatchjs.org/guide

Comment: Thanks a lot, I have intermediate skills on python too, forgot to mention, meanwhile I found that python is right next to java for selenium :)

Comment: @Towkir was my answer helpful enough? If yes, then please check it as an answer. Then the question will be marked as resolved :)

Answer (score 1):

Selenium is written in Java and most examples are in java, but has bindings to many languages, including javascript, so you should be fine.

When looking for free online resources on the web, Google is your best friend :-)

There are minimal differences between Java and Javascript, learn how to translate java examples to javascript.

Also, look at Karma, javascript-based testing framework for Angular using selenium (created/supported by Google). All those examples would be in Javascript.